# Why my terminal opens a dir without cd today?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, cd-command, xfce4-terminal

I'm on Xubuntu 18.04, and everytime I typed `vim` in the terminal, It opened vim editor. But today, It opens a directory named vim! what can cause that? I just changed my font size from 14 to 13 yesterday! I don't remember if I have installed any plugins. (I installed some vim plugins yesterday, but they where just related to vim! And also it works when I type any directory name, also it works when I type `..` or `...` and ... (Up a dir). (I have tried restarting which did't help).

Comment: What is the output of `type -a vim`? it sounds like you may have an alias

Comment: @steeldriver `vim is /usr/bin/vim`